# Trying to post json to node JS server with curl but times out

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, node.js, heroku

### Hey,

### I'm working on a Facebook messenger bot that is hosted on a nodejs server and accesses data from a custom API.

I'm trying to send send data to my nodejs server with curl.
What happens is that I receive the data, and I'm able send a messenger message with that data but in the background my curl request times out.

---

Here's my curl request

```php
   $data = array(
        "textValue" => $messageFB,
        "sender_id" => $questionCreator['bot_fb_sender_id'],
        'notify' => 1
    );

    $data_string = json_encode($data)

    $ch = curl_init('some url');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1);

    $res  = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

---

Here's how I receive it with nodeJS

```js
app.post('/notify', (req, res) => {

    if (req.body.notify > 0) {
        var user = {
          id: req.body.sender_id
        }
        console.log("value of id extern : " + user.id);
        var text = [];

        text[0] = {"text": req.body.textValue.replace(/<[^>]*>?/gm, '')};

        call.SendAction(user);
        call.SendApi(user, text);
    }
});
```

---

This is the error I get

```
at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/notify" host=team-bot-4858.herokuapp.com request_id=818b120b-4305-4aa6-ba4d-80dff02f61b9 fwd="176.162.183.225" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http
```

---

#### EDIT

- I tried to increase the timeout for my curl request by setting
  `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT to 0` and `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT to 400` but it didn't change the result still having timeouts.
- After some digging around in my error_log file I found the cause of timeout (I think...) the error is below.

```
curl_exec(): supplied resource is not a valid cURL handle resource
```

---

#### PS :

- I'm fairly new to web development so my choice of words or
  description might not be very clear
- I apologize in advance for my English also (not my mother tongue).

Comment: Increase the timeouts, and see if the results differ? If so, start measuring which parts of your script take how much time - and whether the API call consumes most of that, or maybe something in your script itself.

Comment: curl with PHP language?

Comment: Yes the language is PHP for my curl request. I will try to increase the timeouts and see if the result differ but I'm not sure will fix this issue but its worth a shot